# How do I draw the moderators' attention to a question wrongly closed?

Tags: discussion

In some occasions I found old questions (not mine) that were wrongly closed as "non constructive" or "off topic" or the like, where either no explanation was given about why, or the explanation given was inconsistent.
In those occasions I commented to express my disagreement.
I would have expected either (a) some moderetor to reconsider and reopen the question, or (b) some comment in response to mine to prove me wrong.
Neither ever happened.

Is that the "expected behaviour", or am I missing a better way to report wrongly closed questions other than commenting to say "hey, this question shouldn't be closed"?

Comment: When you leave a comment, what do you say?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a rather "busy" web site, to say the least.  You can't expect personal attention.

Comment: "How do I draw the moderators' attention to a question wrongly closed?" - You don't, because reopening questions is not a job for moderators. If you think it's wrongly closed, drop into a related chat room and ask people if they think it should be reopened. Beware however that if the question is crap, you will probably not find enough people willing to reopen it, even if the chosen close reason doesn't fit very well.

Comment: You make more chance if you drop in a chatroom to find some users that can verify if you are correct AND have the rep (>3K) to cast re-open votes. Do notice that not all chatrooms are open for this kind of moderation.

Comment: And if they tell you are wrong, take their advice to hart, since they are probably right then.

Comment: If you think that "hey, this question shouldn't be closed" is sufficient justification to let a moderator consider the opinion of *one* user more important than the decision of five or more other users then look no further, they will certainly ignore that.  Try using IMHO instead of "hey".

Comment: Come on, the "Hey this questions should not be closed" comment was just an oversimplified example, it obviously wasn't LITRERALLY the kind of comment I would leave in those situations. I'm astonished that it was taken literally, i thought this was pretty obvious. In each case, I specify *why* I consider the closing to be wrong. But I admit, I rarely if ever use "IMHO".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you try to say in the comments, but leaving a comment that simply says "hey, this question shouldn't be closed" is only slightly more effective that shouting that out your window.  If 5 people voted to close the question, then it is very likely that the question is unclear.

So the most important thing to do is make sure the question is **clear**.

- If you leave a comment, the comment should explain why the question should be reopened.
- If you have enough rep (2K), you should try to edit the question to clarify it.  If you don't have 2K rep yet, you can certainly try to suggest a clarifying edit, but depending on how much you feel you need to change to clarify the question, you will run the risk of the edit getting rejected for changing too much.  Depending on when the question was closed, editing will automatically throw the question into the reopen queue.
- If you have enough rep (3K), you can vote to reopen.  You just need 4 more people to agree and the question will be reopened.

Without enough rep, your options are limited.  The best thing to do is what [rene suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284495/how-do-i-draw-the-moderators-attention-to-a-question-wrongly-closed#comment147409_284495) and pop into an appropriate chat room to bring the question and the need to reopen it to the attention of the community.  They may not agree with you, but if they do, you should get enough reopen votes.

And lastly, there are a lot of questions that seem clear and seem constructive, that are off-topic based on the guidelines of the community.  Before starting on your quest to reopen a question, you should review the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center.  One particular item that is oft-misunderstood is tool requests.  These are often very clear, but are closed because such questions are not welcome by the community.